# postgres create table

Tags: sql, postgresql, hive, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying yo create a table unfortunately i'm getting an error.
Here is the query that i'm running:

```
CREATE TABLE UpStreamParam (
macaddress  CHAR(20),
datats BIGINT,
cmtstimestamp BIGINT,
modulation INT,
chnlidx  INT,
severity BIGINT,
rxpower  FLOAT,
sigqnoise FLOAT,
noisedeviation  FLOAT,
prefecber  FLOAT,
uncorrectables  BIGINT)
STORED AS ORC tblproperties ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY", "orc.bloom.filter.columns"="macaddress")
LOCATION '/usr/hive/warehouse/UpStreamParam'
PARTITIONED BY(cmtsid CHAR(50), date int);
```

This is the error that i'm getting

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "STORED"
LINE 21: STORED AS ORC tblproperties ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY", "orc.b...
```

Any idea how to solve it?

I have version 8.4.20

Comment: what is `STORED`? I don't see it in the [formal syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html)

Comment: Have you tried taking the STORED/LOCATION out first and then run the query?

Comment: Where in the [Postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) did you find the `stored as` or `location` or `partitioned by` options? You also most probably do **not** want to use `float`. See http://floating-point-gui.de/ for details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must eliminate this part:

```
STORED AS ORC tblproperties ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY", "orc.bloom.filter.columns"="macaddress")
LOCATION '/usr/hive/warehouse/UpStreamParam'
PARTITIONED BY(cmtsid CHAR(50), date int);
```

since these kinds of physical storage specifications are not allowed in PostgreSQL. See the [Create Table page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/sql-createtable.html).

Comment: It depends on your objectives. The location probably means using a [TABLESPACE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html). For the storage propoerties you have a choice of physical organizations that are described in the CREATE TABLE page, as well as under the [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/storage-toast.html) name in Postgresql. Finally for partitions you can look here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: Keeping in mind that the PostgreSQL version 8.4 is no longer supported, if you mean the "STORED AS... etc" this has not ever been a PostgreSQL syntax. If you mean the alternatives that I proposed to you in the previous comment the answer is yes.

Comment: it's always nice to find the same solution of your university professor. Hello prof. @Renzo nice to meet you here